# How does AUCTeX determine the documentclass?

Tags: latex, auctex

It's clear that AUCTeX has some way of determining the documentclass, since some functions behave differently depending on which documentclass is selected.  For example, `LaTeX-insert-item` behaves differently when the documentclass is beamer.

I'm writing some custom code that needs to test what the documentclass is.  Obviously, I could roll my own code to do this, but I'd prefer to use the same functionality as AUCTeX.  Is there a function or variable in AUCTeX that contains this information?  I looked, but did not find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AUCTeX doesn't really know the class used in a document, all the packages and class loaded are listed in the variable `TeX-active-styles`.  The only problem with it is that it mixes packages and classes, but this isn't usually a big deal since packages tend not to have the same name of a class.

You can search for the wanted package/class with `member`:

```lisp
(if (member "beamer" TeX-active-styles)
    ;; true...
  ;; false...
  )
```

In addition, starting from AUCTeX 11.88 there is also the possibility to check for the options passed to a specific package or class (and here packages and classes are separated) with functions `LaTeX-provided-class-options-member` and `LaTeX-provided-package-options-member`, but if there are no options passed to a package/class these functions are useless.

Before version 11.88, all the options were listed in `TeX-active-styles` too, making it impossible to distinguish between options and packages/classes.

---

Actually, the different behavior you describe for `\item` is obtained by adding the `("itemize" . LaTeX-item-beamer)` entry to `LaTeX-item-list` in `style/beamer.el`, so `TeX-active-styles` is not used at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can check `TeX-style-hook-list`:

```
(if (member '("beamer") TeX-style-hook-list)
    (message "beamer is used")
  (message "beamer is not used") )
```

**Edit**

My solution is based on expecting aux file auctex creates for each tex file you visit. When I wrote this solution emacs parsed that file and it worked. Now when I open the same tex file emacs doesn't seem to read this file anymore. So one has to force emacs to read it:

```
(load (concat (file-name-directory buffer-file-name)
              TeX-auto-local
              "/"
              (file-name-sans-extension (file-name-nondirectory  buffer-file-name))
              ".el") )
(if (member '("beamer") TeX-style-hook-list)
    (message "beamer is used")
  (message "beamer is not used") )
```

then it works.

Comment: The whole `load` can be reduced to `(TeX-normal-mode)`, but querying `TeX-style-hook-list` with `member` doesn't make sense since it's an alist, `assoc` is more useful.  Anyway, what AUCTeX really does internally is looking at `TeX-active-styles`, not `TeX-style-hook-list`.