# How to check with regular expressions or another way if some package is used in a LaTeX document?

Tags: latex, auctex, regular-expressions

How to check if a specific package is used by a LaTeX document.
For example in the below document (intentionally written in an ugly but technically correct format), the packages fontenc, inputenc, csquotes,
babel, libertine, amsmath, biblatex, filecontents, tikz are used but
lettrine, cleveref, tocloft are not used (because they are in a comment area).

```latex
    \documentclass[ngerman]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc, 
    %babel,
    }
    %\usepackage{cleveref}
    \usepackage
[utf8
]
{inputenc}
    \usepackage{babel, csquotes

    tikz, 
               % lettrine
    amsmath,libertine
    }

    \usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle]{biblatex} 
    \usepackage
    {
    filecontents,

    %tocloft}
    }


    \begin{document}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into `TeX-active-styles` variable.  For this document its value is

```lisp
("url" "ifthen" "logreq" "kvoptions" "keyval" "etoolbox" "biblatex"
 "libertine" "amsopn" "amsbsy" "amstext" "amsmath" "tikz" "csquotes"
 "ngerman" "babel" "" "fontenc" "art10" "article" "latex2e" "z"
 "LATEX")
```

Then the function you should use is `member`:

```lisp
(member "fontenc" TeX-active-styles)
```

This is the same check you should do for classes (see also [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/12538/620)).

In addition, if you want to check whether a certain option has been passed to package there is `LaTeX-provided-package-options-member`

```lisp
(LaTeX-provided-package-options-member "fontenc" "T1")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for mentioning `TeX-active-styles`. I found it very useful variable. This correctly answers the question without using regular expressions.